# using external javascript library with vite in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I have a Laravel project and I am using vue3 with vite now I am facing a problem whenever I try to add any other javascript source it will not work and I don't see any error or warnings in the console, I also tried rearranging the script tags and it's still not working, I even tried to add the script in the input array in vite and it's still not working

here is my vite.config.js

```
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
       
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
            '@': '/resources/js',
        },
    },
});
```

here is the blade file where i load the app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        
        {{--Meta--}}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="description" content="Welcome to little more shops">
        <meta name="keywords" content="little more Shops">
        <meta name="author" content="Little More">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
       {{--Links--}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/core.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/vendor_bundle.min.css')}}">

        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/">
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/">



        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/icon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('demo.files/logo/icon_512x512.png') }}">
        <link rel="manifest" href="{{ asset('assets/images/manifest/manifest.json')}}">

        {{-- Title --}}
        <title>Welcome to Little More Shops</title>


        <style>
            .loading{
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
            }

            .no-js #loader { display: none;  }
            .js #loader {
                 display: block;
                 position: absolute;
                 left: 100px;
                 top: 0;
                }
            .se-pre-con {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/icon.png) center no-repeat #fff;
            }
           </style>




           @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>






    </head>
    <body>
        {{--  <div class="se-pre-con"></div>  --}}

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="app">
            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/core.min.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

now I am trying to load the core.min.js script but it's not working also core.min.js is dependent on another scripts in the folder but it's not required for me to include all the scripts in the blade file

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out if anyone is facing the same problem, the problem is that the script is not communicating directly with the component so what I did is create a global function in the script and call the function in the component

in core.min.js

```
   window.functionname = function (){
      // the script function 
    }
```

in your vue component

```
export default {
mounted() {
 if (typeof window.functionname === 'function') {
   window.functionname();
 }
}
}
</script>
```